# Running LevelDB on Lustre filesystem

Tags: filesystems, cluster-computing, leveldb, lustre

I am running a piece of code that's based on LevelDB. It works fine in my workstation, but when I deploy it into a cluster (with Lustre file system), the program breaks with an "Invalid argument" error. This error is thrown by LevelDB.

What I have found in the web after several hours of reading is that LevelDB cannot be run in a cluster or multiprocess environment. I am not trying to do anything in parallel with the LevelDB database, but it seems that LevelDB just does not like that file system.

Does anybody have suggestions to make LevelDB run in a cluster with shared file system? Is that even possible? Any considerations I should take into account?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's not levelDb, but in order for this to work for sqlite I had to mount my lustre cluster  with the `-localflock` option. This is the solutions for some other databases as well.